# Why does ENOENT mean "No such file or directory"?

Tags: c, linux, unix

What does the `ENT` mean in `ENOENT`?

Shouldn't the error:

> No such file or directory

just be named by `ENOFILE`?

Is there any story or reason?

Answer (score 1132, accepted):

It's an abbreviation of Error NO ENTry (or Error NO ENTity), and can actually be used for more than files/directories.

It's abbreviated because C compilers at the dawn of time didn't support more than 8 characters in symbols.

Comment: "can actually be used for more than files/directories." -- except when you want to have your code merged into Linux: https://lkml.org/lkml/2012/12/23/75

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude’s comment explained most of my questions (qualms) about C naming conventions.

Comment: This answer claims it can be used “for more.”  What are those other things specifically?

Comment: @Jackson such as for `command not found` in node's [child_process](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v10.x/api/child_process.html). \*cries\*.

Comment: @amn well, if you get such a code from a syscall not working with files or directories, you'd be confused by what `strerror` gives you.

Comment: @Jackson: `AF_ALG` sockets will return `ENOENT` from `bind()` if you attempt to bind an algorithm that doesn't exist.

Comment: @caf: `bind()` binds to a socket, not to an algorithm, and `ENOENT` is returned, when a component of a socket pathname does not exist. Actually, whatever `ENOENT` is returned for, it always refers to a file.

Comment: @GuidoFlohr: No, `bind()` binds a socket to an address.  In the case of `AF_ALG` sockets, the address (`sockaddr_alg`) specifies an algorithm type and name, and `ENOENT` is returned for unknown algorithm names.  These algorithm names do not refer to files.

Comment: @caf: Okay, got it. But it's Linux specific and it could be argued that `ENOENT` is the wrong error code for this particular case, exactly because it has nothing to with  a directory entry and it may cause confusing error messages.

Comment: so we're stuck with problems from the past instead of evolving...

Answer (score 147):

It's simply “No such directory entry”. Since directory entries can be directories or files (or symlinks, or sockets, or pipes, or devices), the name `ENOFILE` would have been too narrow in its meaning.

Comment: Symlinks, sockets, pipes, and devices are all files, and so are directories.  ENOFILE would be just as wide or narrow in its meaning as ENOENT.

Comment: In any case, it's safe to say that "ent" stands for the same thing in `ENOENT` as it does in `struct dirent`.

Answer (score 9):

For a full list of all the codes and a better description of what each one means see [errno.h](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.5.0?topic=files-errnoh-symbolic-constants-errno)
This is an include file that is part of the C standard library and the comments clarify what the error is about.
In this case:

> #define ENOENT           2      /* No such file or directory */

Comment: Link is broken -- now requires authentication

Comment: Sigh. Here's an alternative link https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/zos/2.3.0?topic=files-errnoh-symbolic-constants-errno. If hat breaks, this should always work https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=errno.h&ia=web :-)

Answer (score 1):

In linux(Ubuntu)

```
File: /usr/include/asm-generic/errno-base.h
6: #define  ENOENT       2  /* No such file or directory */
7:
```

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html

```
errno 2
```

return:

```
ENOENT 2 No such file or directory
```

open group:
https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009604599/functions/xsh_chap02_03.html

> [ENOENT]
> No such file or directory. A component of a specified pathname does not exist, or the pathname is an empty string.

Glibc:
https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Error-Codes.html

> Macro: int ENOENT
>
> ```
> "No such file or directory." This is a “file doesn’t exist” error for ordinary files that are referenced in contexts where they are
> ```
>
> expected to already exist.