# Appium for testing web application in Android (Nexus 7 - Simulator)

Tags: appium

Anyone using Appium for Web Application testing in Android?

Currently i am using Appium for automating my web application in IOS Simulator(IPad) and it is working fine. I want to use it for Android too i.e (Nexus7 Simulator in Mac machine).

I have tried with below desired capabilities...

```
            DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
            capabilities.setCapability("device", "selendroid");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.VERSION, "4.2.2");
            capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.PLATFORM, "Mac");
            driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
```

But i am getting below error...

> Got configuration error, not starting session info: Responding to
>   client with error: {"status":6,"value":{"message":"A session is either
>   terminated or not started (Original error: ENOENT, stat
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.2.sdk/Applications')","errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.2.sdk/Applications","origValue":"ENOENT,
>   stat
>   '/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.2.sdk/Applications'"},"sessionId":null} POST /wd/hub/session

I am using below versions:-
1) Appium 0.10.4
2) Mac 10.7.5
3) Selenium WebDriver 2.41
4) Android - 4.2.2 API level 17
5) Nexus7 Simulator.

Can anyone help me in solving this issue?

Thanks in Advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the `platformName` capability, so it's trying to use iOS's simulator

> `"errno":34,"code":"ENOENT","path":"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.2.sdk/Applications"`

It's looking for iPhoneSimulator4.2.2.sdk, so it thinks you're using an iPhone simulator and [it can't find the directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902880/3622606) for version 4.2.2 on iPhone so it fails.

**[Read the documentation on DesiredCapabilities](http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#toc_52)**

Additional issues with your DesiredCapabilities:

You're setting `device` to `selendroid` -- you should be setting `deviceName` to `Nexus7 Simulator` (or whatever the process name is for that simulator)

Also you're pointing the webdriver to localhost, which I don't think works? It should be `0.0.0.0:4732/wd/hub`