# ionic serve don't run give me "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory"

Tags: ionic-framework

I work in ionic framework and create new project 
after that when i run

> ionic serve

the browser open and give me this msg 
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/.../ionicProject/www/index.html'

Answer (score 1):

File names are case sensitives, maybe you should go to check it.

Comment: There is not enough information in the question. are u sure?

Comment: I happened to meet similar problem, and I solved it by changing upper case to low case in import statements.

Comment: guess u r right [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory)