# How to automate the build from the following configuration using gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, gulp, loopback

**Backdrop**

I have a loopback and Angular app, Loopback gives use the server models and api's and using its sdk we are able to get client services.

Now i am planning to automate the following build process using gulp.
If any changes in the model is made then the sdk command is run and also the server is restarted/ and secondly when any changes to the angular files the sdk files are run and files are fetched from angular dist folder and server is restarted and best possible we can use live reload of browser.

Here is what i have tried and this never seems to work have been working on this for days.

**Update**

I was able to automate most of the stuff the one place where it fails is

```
gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync.init(null, {
    proxy: 'http://localhost:3000/home',
    browser: 'google chrome',
    port: 7000,
  });
  gulp.watch(['client/src/app/*.ts'], browserSync.reload);
  let watcher = gulp.watch(['./common/models/**.js', './server/**.js', 'gulpfile.js'], ['sdk', 'server']);
  watcher.on('change', function(event) {
    console.log('File ' + event.path + ' was ' + event.type + ', running tasks...'); // this watcher
  });
});

gulp.task('sdk', function() {
  spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

This watcher restarts the server and runs the sdk but it is failing in the sdk

The stack trace please help

```
via remoting. The Angular code for this scope won't be generated.
[19:29:37] Starting 'sdk'...
[19:29:37] Finished 'sdk' after 11 ms
[19:29:37] Starting 'server'...
[19:29:37] Finished 'server' after 17 ms
events.js:163
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn ./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk ENOENT
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1050:11)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:193:32)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:367:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:80:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

**Update**

I have multiple gulp task and one such is `ng build -w` which happens in a new directory for the same i change the `process.chdir` to change path and i also keep tab of this sdk  so do i need to check the path again her . How can i check or give absolute paths in my spawn  . if this is one of the probable causes of failure

Comment: It believes that `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk` doesn't exist. Can you confirm it definitely does?

Comment: Or more specifically, it can't find it in relation to your gulpfile, or the directory that you're running gulp itself from. The ENOENT is an error that relates to spawn not finding the file in question. I'm writing these as comments because I can't 100% say it's all the answer is down to, but let me know if it helps in some way and I'll see if I can form a more solid answer.

Comment: Can you be positive about ./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk? Does it exist?

Comment: Yes if i run it stand alone it works onlyy that task

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Taking into account your update**

What might be happening is that once you change your directory using `process.chdir` for a sepearate task and also you have kept watch on all the tasks . The path is set to the previous path and the gulp task is not able to find the sdk i:e `spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q'], {stdio: 'inherit'});` in that respective path .

To fix this you can add the following check in the `sdk task`

```
gulp.task('sdk', function() {
  if (process.cwd() != __dirname) { // this checks for the current path 
    process.chdir(<change path>); // if it dosent match your base path change it here
  }
  spawn('./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk', ['server/server.js', './client/src/app/shared/sdk', '-q'], {stdio: 'inherit'});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you've run `npm install --save-dev @mean-expert/loopback-sdk-builder`?
2. Are you sure that `gulpfile.js` is in the same dir as `package.json`?
3. Are you certain `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk` exists?
4. Have you tried reinstalling everything?

---

The answer to the error is simply that your spawn function can't find `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk`. This is either because the file doesn't exist, or because the it can't be found *relatively to your gulpfile.js*

The [ENOENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory) error in the console means "error: no entity". It comes from UNIX, rather than Node itself, and basically just translates to "file not found", but applies to a variety of generic things, not just files/directories.

Check that the file `./node_modules/.bin/lb-sdk` definitely exists. Then check that your gulpfile is in the root relative to that directory.

Comment: As a note, I thought I would try out your code. I assume the binary is coming from [loopback-sdk-builder](https://github.com/mean-expert-official/loopback-sdk-builder). I got it to work fine, myself

Comment: I think so for one of my tasks i change ir using.process and inthink i need to change agin relative to this, how can i do that

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your question

Comment: my question is , i am changing the directory paths for one of the tasks and watching over this sdk . do i need to check the directory again here and if not put the prompt in tghe corrrect position or how can i have a static path for my indivdual process