# WHAT DOES THIS ERROR MEAN - error: bundling failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/Users/davidarebuwa/jaro/app/app/img'

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

Can someone help me make sense of what the terminal is trying to say to me?

I am trying to create a login for my app, and each time i refresh the simulator i get this error: failed to load bundle

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does ENOENT mean "No such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory)

Answer (score 0):

So, i think, terminal said you, that it can't find directory with path `'/Users/davidarebuwa/jaro/app/app/img'`