# pm2 managed process in errored state after machine reboot

Tags: javascript, pm2, laravel-echo, process-management

I'm using [pm2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io) (version 3.4.1) to manage the [Laravel Echo websocket server](https://github.com/laravel/echo). It runs perfect, but I'm trying to get it to auto-start after a machine reboot (which runs Ubuntu 16.04). To do this I followed [these instructions](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/startup/):

```
$ pm2 startup
[PM2] Init System found: systemd
[PM2] To setup the Startup Script, copy/paste the following command:
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u kramer65 --hp /home/kramer65

$ sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 startup systemd -u kramer65 --hp /home/kramer65
[sudo] password for kramer65: 
[PM2] Init System found: systemd
Platform systemd
Template
[Unit]
Description=PM2 process manager
Documentation=https://pm2.keymetrics.io/
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=kramer65
LimitNOFILE=infinity
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
Environment=PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
Environment=PM2_HOME=/home/kramer65/.pm2
PIDFile=/home/kramer65/.pm2/pm2.pid

ExecStart=/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 resurrect
ExecReload=/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 reload all
ExecStop=/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 kill

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

Target path
/etc/systemd/system/pm2-kramer65.service
Command list
[ 'systemctl enable pm2-kramer65' ]
[PM2] Writing init configuration in /etc/systemd/system/pm2-kramer65.service
[PM2] Making script booting at startup...
[PM2] [-] Executing: systemctl enable pm2-kramer65...
[PM2] [v] Command successfully executed.
+---------------------------------------+
[PM2] Freeze a process list on reboot via: $ pm2 save

[PM2] Remove init script via: $ pm2 unstartup systemd
```

So then I ran `pm2 save`:

```
$ pm2 save
[PM2] Saving current process list...
[PM2] Successfully saved in /home/kramer65/.pm2/dump.pm2
```

After this I reboot the machine, ssh back in, and check pm2 processes:

```
$ pm2 status
┌──────────┬────┬─────────┬──────┬─────┬─────────┬─────────┬────────┬─────┬────────┬────────┬──────────┐
│ App name │ id │ version │ mode │ pid │ status  │ restart │ uptime │ cpu │ mem    │ user   │ watching │
├──────────┼────┼─────────┼──────┼─────┼─────────┼─────────┼────────┼─────┼────────┼────────┼──────────┤
│ echo     │ 0  │ N/A     │ fork │ N/A │ errored │ 0       │ 0      │ 0%  │ 0 B    │ kramer65 │ disabled │
└──────────┴────┴─────────┴──────┴─────┴─────────┴─────────┴────────┴─────┴────────┴────────┴──────────┘
 Use `pm2 show <id|name>` to get more details about an app
```

As you can see the status is errored. If I stop and start the process (`pm2 stop echo && pm2 start echo`) the process runs again.

The error log (~/.pm2/pm2.log) tells me this:

```
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: --- New PM2 Daemon started ----------------------------------------------------
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Time                 : Tue May 14 2019 11:56:36 GMT+0200 (CEST)
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: PM2 version          : 3.4.1
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Node.js version      : 8.15.1
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Current arch         : x64
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: PM2 home             : /home/kramer65/.pm2
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: PM2 PID file         : /home/kramer65/.pm2/pm2.pid
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: RPC socket file      : /home/kramer65/.pm2/rpc.sock
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: BUS socket file      : /home/kramer65/.pm2/pub.sock
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Application log path : /home/kramer65/.pm2/logs
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Process dump file    : /home/kramer65/.pm2/dump.pm2
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: Concurrent actions   : 2
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: SIGTERM timeout      : 1600
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: ===============================================================================
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: App [echo:0] starting in -fork mode-
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 log: App [echo:0] online
2019-05-14T11:56:36: PM2 error: Error: spawn node ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:190:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:362:16)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:139:11)
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:219:9)
```

Does anybody have any idea what's going wrong here?

Comment: What does `journalctl -u service-name.service` say?

Comment: What's your pm2 version ?

Comment: @suv - Do you mean literally `journalctl -u service-name.service`? That says `No journal files were opened due to insufficient permissions.`, and if I call it with `sudo` I get `-- No entries --`. I assume you mean that I have to change `service-name` for something else though.

Comment: @MehdiBenmoha - I'm using pm2 version `3.4.1`. I also added to the question.

Comment: @kramer65 - No. Not literally. Invoke the command with the name of the service. Most probably it is pm2-kramer65.service so it becomes `journalctl -u pm2-kramer65.service`

Comment: Under my `Target path` in my first output it says it wrote to `/etc/systemd/system/pm2-kramer65.service`, so I ran `journalctl -u pm2-kramer65.service` (with and without `sudo`) and I get the same as before. Either `insufficient permissions` or `-- No entries --`. Any ideas?

Comment: Also if you have a `process.yml` post it. And the pm2 config.js file in `$HOME/.pm2/conf.js`

Comment: What's the output of `systemctl list-unit-files --all` ?

Comment: You need to add all dependecies in this section After=network.target. What type of services do this application use?

Comment: @suv - There's a lot of output for `systemctl list-unit-files --all`, and `pm2-kramer65.service                         enabled` is one of them. That is both after rebooting the machine (when echo is in `errored` state) and also after stopping and starting echo to get it to work again.

Comment: @suv - `$HOME/.pm2/conf.js` doesn't exist. `~/.pm2/module_conf.json` does exist, but that just contains an empty json object (`{}`). I can't find any `process.yml` file. Where could that be?

Comment: @kramer65 Which command are you exactly running with pm2? Can you paste the result of `pm2 info echo`, especially the first part "Describing process"?

Answer (score 8):

`ENOENT` stands for [No such directory entry](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902880/7295772)

## What is `env <command>` doing? ([by Chris Johnsen](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/103474/214017))

The [`env` command](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uenv.htm) is used to run another program in a custom environment without modifying the current one.

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin \
   /usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2 \
   startup systemd -u kramer65 --hp /home/kramer65
```

> **Installation** note from [pm2 documentation](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/startup-hook/#installation)
>   To detect available init systems on your machine and generate a configuration, use:

```
pm2 startup
$ [PM2] You have to run this command as root. Execute the following command:
$ sudo su -c env PATH=$PATH:/home/unitech/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3/bin pm2 startup <distribution> -u <user> --hp <home-path>
```

I will break down the command as follows

```
sudo env name=value name2=value2 program and args
```

1) The **program**

runs the command **program** `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2`

> The first remaining argument specifies the program name to invoke; it is searched for according to the `PATH' environment variable.

2) The **arguments** passed

> Any remaining arguments are passed as arguments to that program.

The `args` passed to `pm2` cli command are `startup systemd -u kramer65 --hp /home/kramer65`.

- the `startups` command will simply set `pm2` to start at boot ([Startup Cli Commands](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/features/commands-cheatsheet/))
- the `systemd` command is used for supported init systems `Ubuntu => 16, CenOS >=7, Arch, Debian >=7` ([Startup Hooks Compatability](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/startup-hook/#compatibility)) and should be changed to the correct `platform` as by the included docs.

3) The **environment** used to execute the program

> with an environment formed by extending the current environment with the environment variables and values designated by name=value and name2=value2.

As by the `pm2` docs should be a folder inside `/home/kramer/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3/bin`

```
PATH=$PATH:/home/unitech/.nvm/versions/node/v4.3/bin
```

while you are using a folder outside of your `home` directory because you are running an old version on `nodejs` (see last chapter **Nodejs installed in usr/bin/node**).

```
PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin
```

4) **User** permissions

you are passing `--user kramer65 --home-path /home/kramer65` to the `pm2` cli command.

```
-u <user> --hp <home-path>
```

## Save your process

> The startup hook auto load the process list that you have previously saved.
>   Save your process list with:

```
pm2 save
```

## `Nodejs` installed in `usr/bin/node` ([Error: spawn ENOENT on Ubuntu 14.04](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/708#issuecomment-126612436))

> How to reproduce: you have two version of nodejs on your computer. One is an old version installed in `/usr/bin/node` and the other one is a recent version located in  `./nodejs/node`. I launch my pm2 manager programmatically, by calling `./nodejs/node myManager.js`, which will call pm2.connect(), which will try to spawn the PM2 Daemon.
>
> What happen is that the PM2 Daemon will be launched using the old node binary from `/usr/bin/node` instead of the recent node binary running my myManager.js script (locatedin `./nodejs/node`).
>
> What this does is look for a node binary in the current directory, and then default to node binaries in the path. *BUT* the node binary running the current code is in `./nodejs/node`. To launch the PM2 daemon with the same node binary as the current process, you need to use process.execPath

You can read [more info at](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_execpath)  and [in the relevant discussion](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2/issues/708#issuecomment-126612436)

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. It took me some time to comprehend it. I just don't understand what you mean with `the other one is a recent version located in ./nodejs/node`. That is a relative path. I did a search on my systen (`sudo find / -name *node*`) and didn't find any other node version. Or is it simply looking for another node version which it doesn't find. Could you give me any more hints as to where this could go wrong?

Comment: @kramer65 sorry i was on an 18 hours flight.  I m answering from a mobile device.  I quoted a message from a discussion.  Seems that it is not finding the folder for `/usr/local/share/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/pm2/bin/pm2` in y child process? Y are passing [user home](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/guide/startup-hook/#user-permissions) `--hp /home/kramer` but yarn is installing dependencies outside of y home folder.  I would consider upgrading yarn and node

Comment: I don t believe the issue is the `--hp` option,  but your `systemmd` not finding a folder from the `pm2` path

Comment: This issue could be solved after better understanding how systemmd works,  spawning a terminal session into systemmd and testing those commands