# expo build failed ENOENT

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

Facing this error after calling expo `build:android`.
Can anyone check what's the issue ? I'm using `windows 8` OS and `yarn`.

[image: image error]

**app.json**

```
"expo": {
    "name": "GTechApp",
    "slug": "GTechApp",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "icon": "./assets/images/icons/logo.png",
    "platforms": [
      "ios",
      "android",
      "web"
    ],
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
    "ios": {
      "bundleIdentifier": "com.gtech.gtechapp",
      "buildNumber": "1.0.0",
    },
    "android": {
      "package": "com.gtech.gtechapp",
      "versionCode": 1,
      "icon": "./assets/images/icons/logo.png"
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory - maybe this will give you some pointers. ENOENT explanation...

Comment: the meaning was explained. But I'm not sure which part exactly the error coming.

Comment: I would hazard something in that cross-spawn\lib folder is missing.. Maybe you have something missing in your dependencies somewhere? I used Ionic / Angular so have a bit of familiarity with these types of messages. I would imagine there are Github project pages for React.. Use Google to constrain the search term on that domain and see if it's been raised before perhaps.

Comment: Thanks guys. I fixed it be after doing different experiment. Just delete the folder /android and /ios on the root folder. and run build again