# Why does it give me an enoent error every time I start the project with npm start?? nextjs

Tags: javascript, next.js

I have this problem with nextjs how do fix it ??
PS C:\Users\capas\Desktop\00\React\ecotask> npm start

> ecotask@0.1.0 start
> next start

▲ Next.js 14.0.2

- Local:        http://localhost:3000

[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\capas\Desktop\00\React\ecotask.next\BUILD_ID'] {
errno: -4058,
code: 'ENOENT',
syscall: 'open',
path: 'C:\Users\capas\Desktop\00\React\ecotask\.next\BUILD_ID'
}

I used npm install and other commands found but nothing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does ENOENT mean "No such file or directory"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19902828/why-does-enoent-mean-no-such-file-or-directory). Look at the two paths shown above, one is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the file not found. To start a newly created NextJs app using npm, use `npm run dev`

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "lint": "next lint"
  },
```